# Get face book user's info which are like/share some object

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I search any possible ways to get users info throw fb `api`.

`{user-id}` method return info about only first and last name.

What i actualy need:

- get all users which are like or share some post on the wall
- collect info about this users (countries, cities, age e.t.c.)

Answer (score 0):

General rule: No user information without authorizing that user. Without authorization, you can only get the name of the user. You would not be allowed to do anything with the data anyway, without asking each and every user.

If you want to know statistics, just use the Page Insights. There´s nothing for user profiles though.